# Minkowski's integral inequality for other norms

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, integral-inequality

In my measure theory course we studied norms $L_p$ and no other norms. For proofs we used exclusively the trick known as [Hoelder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) which works only on $L_p$ norms. I disliked it very much so I found a proof for [Minkowski's integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality) which (slightly longer but) works for all norms that are monotone in this sense:

1. $f\le g\;\;\;\text{a.e.}\;\Rightarrow\;|f|\le|g|\;\;\;\;\;$ (also, $\;\;f=g\;\;\;\text{a.e.}\;\Rightarrow\;|f|=|g|$),
2. $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;\;\text{is non-decreasing w.r.t. the relation above}\;\Rightarrow\;\lim|f_n|=|\lim f_n|$,
3. $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;\;\text{is non-increasing w.r.t. the relation above}\;\;\land\;\;|f_1|<\infty\;\Rightarrow\;\lim|f_n|=|\lim f_n|$.

Unfortunately, I couldn't prove it for all norms, but this was as general as I could imagine a norm be. Then, the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_one_real_variable) norm was substantially different, so I proved that case too:

Let $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function (it also holds for more general functions, but let's keep it simple). Let $H:\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the norm that maps (Lipschitz continuous) functions $f\in\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ into $|f(0)|+\text{Var}_f[0,1]$. Let $f_x:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:y\mapsto f(x,y)$ and let $f^y:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto f(x,y)$ and let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure. Then we have:
$$H\bigg(x\mapsto\int f_xd\lambda\bigg)\le\int\Big(y\mapsto H(f^y)\Big)d\lambda.$$

On the other hand, I could not find any norm for which this inequality doesn't hold.

**The question:**
Is there any simple norm for which the Minkowski's integral inequality doesn't hold? What is the more precise relationship with the integral operator that the norm has to have in order to satisfy this inequality?
(*The "definition" of the Minkowski's integral "inequality" in case of the general norm is like the one I gave for the total variation norm.*)

Answer (score 0):

The Minkowski integral inequality should hold in extreme generality, as long as one can approximate the function $x\mapsto f_x$ with simple functions in the variable $x$. There is the so-called theory of [“Bochner integration”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) which essentially allows to define the integral of any measurable function defined on a measure space, with values in any given Banach space $X$. For all those functions, the inequality you want always holds. So the integral Minkowski inequality is a quite general feature of Banach spaces.

On the other hand, if the function space you consider is not complete, the integral could easily get outside of the space. For example, if you consider the norm $\|\cdot\|$ which coincides with the $L^1(0,1)$ norm for all compactly supported functions in $(0,1)$ and is $+\infty$ otherwise, you can easily find a counterexample: just consider
$$ f(x,y)=\mathbf 1_{|2y-1|<x}(y). $$
The right hand side of your inequality is 1/2, but the left hand side is $+\infty$, since $\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx=1-2|y-1/2|$, which is not compactly supported on $(0,1)$.

The above example could sound a little artificial, and you might ask whether there is a more natural example. Honestly I don’t know, and the main problem is that many “natural” norms define a Banach space. One should look for a norm which does not define a Banach space, otherwise we fall in the setting of Bochner integration, and the inequality holds for essentially all nice enough functions. Even in that case one could consider the completion of the space and canonically extend the norm over the completion, so I would suspect that the integral inequality holds for any sufficiently “natural” norm.

As a final note, there are indeed much more interesting examples for [quasi-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinorm). In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.00607.pdf) it is proved that Minkowski integral inequality holds (up to a universal multiplicative constant) for the Lorentz spaces $L^{p,r}$ whenever $1<p<\infty$ and $1\leq r\leq\infty$ (see section 3; this is actually a consequence of the fact that those spaces can be given a norm which makes them complete), but it fails when $p=1$ and $r>1$ (see subsec. 4.3).